# Proof that all projections are continuous functions

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, proof-explanation, projection

The question was to prove:

> $P_k:(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n) \to x_k,\ k \in\{ 1, 2,\cdots n\}$ are continuous functions.

The professor proved this by
$$d (x, y) = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2} \to 0\implies  |x_k - y_k| \le d (x, y) \to 0$$
where $d (x, y)$ is the function for finding the distance between $x$ and $y$. I don't really get the logic of the professor.

Can anyone explain what the professor is saying or show a different, easier proof?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

$d(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+\cdots +(x_n-y_n)^2}\ge\sqrt{(x_k-y_k)^2}=|x_k-y_k|$
So given an $\epsilon$ you can take $\delta=\epsilon$, since if you have $d(x,y)< \delta$ then $|x_k-y_k|< \delta=\epsilon$. So the projection function is continuous.

---

The previous answer was using the definition of continuity in real analysis, assuming that you probably have the topology of $\mathbb{R^n}$ defined as the topology generated by open balls (since open balls are defined with the distance function). This definition of continuity is equivalent to the topological one for spaces like $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Maybe you want to use the more general definition of continuity given for topological spaces: a function $f:X\to Y$ between two topological spaces is continuous if given any open set $V\subseteq Y$, its inverse image $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq X$ is an open set (in the topology of $X$).
If that's the case then you probably have the topology of $\mathbb{R^n}$ defined as the product topology of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself $n$ times (the definition saying that a set of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is open if it's the cartesian product of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$). Let's see then if we have continuity with this definition. Take any open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. You can check that its inverse image by the projection function $P_k$ is $P_k^{-1}(V)=\mathbb{R}\times\cdots\times V\times\cdots\mathbb{R}$, where $V$ is in the $\textit{k-th}$ position ($P_k$ is projecting the $\textit{k}$ coordinate of that product). This is an open set by definition, since is the cartesian product of open sets, so the function is continuous.

Comment: What your proffesor was trying to say is that when the distance between $x$ and $y$ get small, the distance between their projections get small too, since making $d(x,y)$ approach $0$ makes $|x_k−y_k|$ go to $0$ too.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation! What I don't get is why the distance function is used for the projection function. Also for x1, x2,...xn do they mean respective points (such as (x,y,z) )  on the graph or respective x values only?

Comment: The $x_i$ are the coordinates of the point $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, since $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$. The distance function is used because we are using the definition of continuity in real analysis, which says that a function is continuous if given a distance $\epsilon$ we can find another distance $\delta$ such that whenever two points are closer than $\delta$ we can assure that their images are closer than $\epsilon$. Basically it is saying that points that are close to each other have images close to each other. I you want to use the topologic definition of continuity, I'm adding it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual topology on $\Bbb R^n$ is the product  (or box, since they agree on a finite product) topology, which by definition is the coarsest topology which makes all the projections continuous.